# Массивы в Java в чем разница?

Tags: java, массивы

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем разница ?

```
String[] bArray = {"a","b","c", "d", "e"};
```

и

```
String[] cArray = new String[]{"a","b","c","d","e"};
```

Comment: интересно, а кто минусует то?

Comment: Второй вариант грамотнее, пиши лучше так, т.к. объяснить это довольно сложно в несколько строк.

Answer (score 3):

Нет никакой разницы, это просто разные способы сделать одно и то же.
Однако первый вариант доступен только при объявлении переменной.

Например нельзя написать:

```
foo.someMethod({x, y});
```

но можно написать:

```
foo.someMethod(new SomeType[] { x, y });
```